# Cordova, Android target installation

Tags: android, cordova

When installing Cordova I get the following error anyone know of an easy fix to this? npm version 5.6, cordova version 8

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
No android targets (SDKs) installed!
Gradle: not installed
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio

Comment: Did you follow all the steps?